# Route53 getHostedZone AccessDenied. User doesn't have permission to call route53:GetHostedZone

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I'm creating an AWS Cloudformation stack in which I'm adding a recordset to an existing Route53 Hosted Zone. The resource is specified as follows (in YAML format):

```
DNS:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup
    Properties:
        HostedZoneName: !Ref HostedZoneName
        Comment: Zone apex alias targeted to myELB LoadBalancer.
        RecordSets:
        - Name: !Join [ ".", ["alb", !Ref HostedZoneName]]
          Type: A
          AliasTarget:
              HostedZoneId: !Ref AliasTargetHostedZoneId
              DNSName: !Ref AliasTargetDNSName
```

`HostedZoneName`, `AliasTargetHostedZoneId` and `AliasTargetDNSName` are passed in as parameters.

The problem I have is that the stack will not create because of the permission error specified in the title. By default CloudFormation will use the permissions of the user creating the stack, me. I have got the AdministratorAccess policy, so I should be allowed to do everything, including all Route53 operations.

I've also tried creating the stack by passing an IAM role which also has the AdministratorAccess policy, which gave me the same error.

All other resources specified in the template (VPC, Loadbalancer, RDS,..) create without problems.

Comment: How do you define and pass the AliasTargetHostedZoneId parameter ?

Comment: @ddewaele the load balancer's  `CanonicalHostedZoneID`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's important to define and pass the correct HostedzoneId into the template.

As you're having admin privileges while executing the CloudFormation scripts, you should be able to add a recordset to a Route53 hosted zone in your account without specifying any additional roles / profiles.

However you need to ensure that the correct HostedzoneId is passed. This is typically done as either a String, or using the [CanonicalHostedZoneID attribute of the load balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer.html).

When passing it as a string you'll need to ensure that the parameter type is of type string, and not [AWS::Route53::HostedZone::Id](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#aws-specific-parameter-types)

Comment: Why `String` rather than the specific type?

Comment: good question on that last point, why? it's fixed my issue (changing the type to a plain string), but is a mystery

Comment: SO to the rescue when AWS' doco is useless. I too used type HostedZone::Id (because why wouldn't I?!) and was slamming my head on my keyboard, until I found this post.

Comment: Re: why string - my inference is that cloudformation makes a call to `route53:GetHostedZone` when using the specific type.  Since the LB's canonical zone is in an AWS-controlled account and this privilege has not been granted to you, it will result in an error like in the original question.